# When can we omit есть?

Tags: словоупотребление

In the village (there is) only one new house
В деревне только один новый дом

Here (there is) only one place
Здесь только одно место

In the apartment (there is) a big room
В квартире большая комната

Why is есть not used in these sentences, i know that it is okay with or without , but when is it acceptable to use it without?

I found an answer here on the stack exchange but the question uses “у меня” and possessive cases and i am particularly looking for a rule that applies to all cases

Comment: Nuances. "В квартире большая комната" - "The apartment has one room, and it's big". "В квартире есть большая комната" - "The apartment has multiple rooms, with one room bigger than others."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just remembered a famous poem for children.

> А у меня в кармане гвоздь. А у вас? –
>   А у нас сегодня гость. А у вас?

1 We don't use есть with most "abstract" nouns which aren't things in the structure у меня /тебя/нас есть, because there's no real posession.

> У нас экзамен в пятницу. У меня сегодня встреча.(compare : У меня есть квартира. У него есть собака. where есть can or cannot be used.)

I think время is an exception.

2. We don't use есть in structures У меня в кармане гвоздь.where we speak about location rather than about posession. Though it's possible.

> У меня в шкафу одеяло.

3. We don't use есть describing appearance or character.

> У нее глаза – два брильянта в три карата. У нее красивые волосы. У него золотое сердце.

4.We don't use есть when there is an attribute before the noun, if the accent is on a quality.

> У него есть брат. But : У него три брата.
>   У него есть машина. But: У него новая машина. У меня есть дом. But : У меня большой дом.

Comment: So do you claim "у меня сегодня есть встреча" is wrong? I downvote this.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is quite clear: you omit 'есть', when this word is not what you underline in your message! That means that omitting does not give you absolutely the same sentences, so you not 'can', but 'do' omit 'есть' when this should be done.

Every school student knows what is the subject and what is the predicate in the sentence. 'есть' is a verb, so it is always a predicate. Predicate contains the core idea of the sentence's subject. But what happens, when you omit the predicate? Yes, other words try to take it's role.

Just compare:

> 'В деревне ***один*** новый дом' = 'A ***single*** new house is in the village' = 'The new house is single in the village'

vs

> 'В деревне ***есть*** один новый дом' = 'A new house ***is*** in the village' = 'A new house can be found in the village'

---

> 'Здесь ***одно*** место' = '***One*** place is here' = 'The place here is the only one'

vs

> 'Здесь ***есть*** одно место' = 'There ***is*** one place' = 'A place is here'

---

> 'В квартире ***большая*** комната' = 'The room in the flat is ***big***'

vs

> 'В квартире ***есть*** большая комната' = 'A big room ***is*** in the flat'

Your sentences contained 'только', which is a possible signal to omit 'есть'.

While explaining I noticed, that 'есть' was omitted in sentences, where 'the' was used in English, while 'a' *was* used with 'есть'. That corresponds with the role strength of the subjects. Maybe it will be the most useful hint for you.

P.S.
This was about regular texts. Steady expression can except this structure (just because they are steady), poems prefer to compress information. You will be understood when breaking these a bit soft rules, but no one always speaks like from a theater scene, right?)

Comment: These examples were extremely helpful, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Most sentences with есть can do without it, like in your examples. There are some exceptions e.g.:

- Дети есть дети. = Children are children.
- У вас есть дети? = Do you have any children?
- У тебя что ли денег нет? - Есть! = Don't you have any money? - I do!

Comment: In your second example, you can still say «У вас дети?» To me, though, it sounds a little different. While «У вас есть дети?» is an abstract question about having or not having children, «У вас дети?» can be about children as source of some problem or another situation. For example, «Почему вы торопитесь домой? У вас дети?»

Answer (score 1):

I think I would add a rather well known song, which has many examples of "есть" used and still some examples of "есть" omitted (mostly to fit the rhymes into the rhythm):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6ZevXca9CI

```
Виктор Цой / Группа КИНО 
Место Для Шага Вперёд

У меня есть дом, только нет ключей, 
У меня есть солнце, но оно среди туч, 
Есть голова, только нет плечей, 
Но я вижу, как тучи режет солнечный луч. 

У меня есть слово, но в нём нет букв, 
У меня есть лес, но нет топоров, 
У меня есть время, но нет сил ждать 
И есть ещё ночь, но в ней нет снов. 

И есть ещё белые, белые дни, 
Белые горы и белый лёд, 
Но всё, что мне нужно, это несколько слов 
И место для шага вперёд. 

У меня река, только нет моста, 
У меня есть мыши, но нет кота, 
У меня есть парус, но ветра нет 
И есть ещё краски, но нет холста. 

У меня на кухне из крана вода, 
У меня есть рана, но нет бинта, 
У меня есть братья, но нет родных 
И есть рука, и она пуста. 

И есть ещё белые, белые дни, 
Белые горы и белый лёд, 
Но всё, что мне нужно, это несколько слов 
И место для шага вперёд. 

И есть ещё белые, белые дни, 
Белые горы и белый лёд, 
Но всё, что мне нужно, это несколько слов 
И место для шага вперёд.
```

Answer (score 0):

The word `есть` is used explicitly when a strong emphasis on a fact of existence should be made.
If it is omitted, emphasis is shifted to elsewhere.